# KeyStore EOFException after getting entry

Tags: java, security, keystore, private-key

I created a `KeyStore` to hold a set of private keys in a web server. After I create the `KeyStore.jks` file I successfully add a private key and retrieve it from the key store. But, when I try to add a new key I get a `EOFException` in the `KeyStore.load(...)`.

```
public void setPrivateKey(String deviceSerialNumber, PrivateKey priv) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException, NotSupportedException {
    File privateKeyFile = getFile(Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_NAME);//Get the KeyStore.jks file
    synchronized (privateKeyFile) {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile), Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_PASSWORD); //This is where the error happens 
        FileOutputStream file = null;
        try {
            file = new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFile);//Get the JKS file with the private keys


            //Write the private key to the file
            KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_PASSWORD);
            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pke = new KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(priv, new Certificate[] { createCertificate() });
            keyStore.setEntry(deviceSerialNumber, pke, protParam);

            //Save changes to key store file
            keyStore.store(file, Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_PASSWORD);

        } finally {
            file.close();//Close the private key file output stream
        }

    }
}

public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String deviceSerialNumber) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, KeyStoreException, InvalidKeySpecException, NotSupportedException, UnrecoverableEntryException {
    PrivateKey key = null;
    File privateKeyFile = getFile(Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_NAME);//Get the keyStore.jks file
    synchronized (privateKeyFile) {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile), Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_PASSWORD);
        FileOutputStream file = null;
        try {
            file = new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFile);//Get the JKS file with the private keys


            //Write the private key to the jks file
            boolean isKeyEntry = keyStore.isKeyEntry(deviceSerialNumber);//Check if there is a key with the alias deviceSerialnumber
            if (isKeyEntry) {//If the key does exist
                System.err.println("Key does exist!!!!1");
                KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_PASSWORD);
                KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pke =  (PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(deviceSerialNumber, protParam);
                key = pke.getPrivateKey();
            } else {//If the key does not exist
                System.err.println("No key!!!!!!!!");
                //HANDLE THIS
                return null;
            }

        } finally {
            file.close();//Close the private key file output stream
        }
    }
    return key;
}

private Certificate createCertificate() throws CertificateException, IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(getFile(Constants.CERTIFICATE_FILE));


    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    Collection<? extends Certificate> c = cf.generateCertificates(fis);
    Iterator<? extends Certificate> i = c.iterator();

    if (i.hasNext())
        return (Certificate) i.next();
    else 
        return null;
}
```

The error happens in `setPrivateKey(...)` at the `keyStore.load(...)`  on the second time that the method is called to add an additional private key to the key store.

I generate the `KeyStore.jks` file and the `server.cer` files using keytool

```
keytool -genkey -alias keyAlias -keyalg RSA  -keystore KeyStore.jks -keypass password -storepass password
keytool -export -alias keyAlias -file server.cer -keystore KeyStore.jks -storepass password
```

Am I doing something wrong in the way I store and retrieve private keys from the keystore ? How do I stop the `EOFException` from happening ?

Comment: Try to remove this line of getPrivateKey: `file = new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFile);` and close the `FileInputStream` you created before, not the output stream

Comment: That did work. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line of `getPrivateKey`

```
file = new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFile);
```

It is not being used and close the FileInputStream you created before, not the output stream. You have two open streams on the same file

```
 keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile), Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_PASSWORD);
```